# app crashes only when downloaded from store - how to test bug fix now?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ios6

I have an app in appstore which worked fine until iOS6.

There it crashes - but only when downloaded from the store. When its installed through xCode there is no crash.

While I read the crash report in the Organizer I get this:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32b6f526 objc_retain + 6
1   XXXX                            0x000cefd8 -[XXXX messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:] (XXXX.m:96)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x348659c0 __invoking___ + 64
3   CoreFoundation                  0x347bcfe6 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 282
4   CoreFoundation                  0x347bcb3e -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 46
5   UIKit                           0x35f89324 -[_UIObjectArgumentReplacingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 300
6   CoreFoundation                  0x34864616 ___forwarding___ + 622
7   CoreFoundation                  0x347bbf64 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
```

So I assume it is line 96 in the file.

This is the code:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //take away the SMS screen fast

    NSString *sms = controller.body;  //**** THIS IS LINE 96

    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            //message.text = @"Canceled";
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent: {
                   NSLog(@"Result: sent %@",sms);
            }
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            //message.text = @"Failed";
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            //message.text = @"Not sent";
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }

    [self.delegate myVCDidFinishWithValue: val];

}
```

So basically I in this case I just take out the complete code since I do not need it anymore.

My question:

**Is there a way now to test the app as if it was loaded from the AppStore so I can check other problems?**

Or do I gamble now and hope the error is gone?

ps when I istall the app through xCode - or even use TestFlight to distribute to testers it worked fine! Only from Appstore it crashes. Any idea if they do anything to the code?

Many thanks!

Comment: xcode -> Product -> edit Scheme -> Run [yourapp].app -> Build Configuration = Release

Comment: Also, you are calling `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]` and in the next line you access the dissmised Controller. This is no good idea also in ios < 6

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I understand waht you mean with the first comment - should I build a release version of the app? How should I install such an app that was created with archive and release settings? I did this for TestFlight as mentioned above - but this code version runs without problems. Regarding your 2. comment: the dismiss of ModalVC is not dismissing itslef but the modelViewController of the SMS dialog. SO there is no problem accessing anything within the active VC. In fact, Apple suggests to always dismiss a presented VC from the presentee - never dismiss itself.

Comment: SMS: yes, but i think you should dismiss it at the bottom of your method. --- Install: You can drag the archived (and stored for enterprise) ipa onto your device in the organizer.

Comment: I need to dismiss it at the beginning - otherwise I cannot dismiss the ViewController that is visible under the SMS viewController (since the SMSModalView which was created on top of the VC is still visible). Install: I'll try that - hopefully this is different from installing an ad hoc through TestFlight. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer - this is a real cool solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should dismiss it at the bottom of your method. --- Install: You can drag the archived (and stored for enterprise) ipa onto your device in the organizer.

(look at comments for detail)

Comment: Thanks very much - I guess dragging is really the only way to get a release version on the iPhone - just run with release does not work! regarding the dismiss of the ModalVC - this is OK, since its releasing the SMS dialog which is not being accessed.